# 'else if' for multiple checkbox combinations

Tags: php, checkbox

I have a form with 4 checkboxes; debut, batted, no and bowled. When adding, if one is checked, it will add in the data with this code (in this instance, debut):

```
if(!empty($_POST["debut"])) {
try
{
$sql = 'INSERT INTO performance SET
    matchid = :matchid,
    playerid = :playerid,
    team = :team,
    debut = 1,
    batted = 0,
    batpos = :batpos,
    runs = :runs,
    ballsfaced = :ballsfaced,
    fours = :fours,
    sixes = :sixes,
    no = 0,
    howout = :howout,
    fielder = :fielder,
    bowler = :bowler,
    bowled = 0,
    ballsbowled = :ballsbowled,
    maidens = :maidens,
    wickets = :wickets,
    runsconceded = :runsconceded,
    catches = :catches,
    stumpings = :stumpings,
    runouts = :runouts';
$s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$s->bindValue(':matchid', $_POST['matchid']);
$s->bindValue(':playerid', $_POST['playerid']);
$s->bindValue(':team', $_POST['team']);
$s->bindValue(':batpos', $_POST['batpos']);
$s->bindValue(':runs', $_POST['runs']);
$s->bindValue(':ballsfaced', $_POST['ballsfaced']);
$s->bindValue(':fours', $_POST['fours']);
$s->bindValue(':sixes', $_POST['sixes']);
$s->bindValue(':howout', $_POST['howout']);
$s->bindValue(':fielder', $_POST['fielder']);
$s->bindValue(':bowler', $_POST['bowler']);
$s->bindValue(':ballsbowled', $_POST['ballsbowled']);
$s->bindValue(':maidens', $_POST['maidens']);
$s->bindValue(':wickets', $_POST['wickets']);
$s->bindValue(':runsconceded', $_POST['runsconceded']);
$s->bindValue(':catches', $_POST['catches']);
$s->bindValue(':stumpings', $_POST['stumpings']);
$s->bindValue(':runouts', $_POST['runouts']);
$s->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
$error = 'Error adding submitted performance.';
include 'error.html.php';
exit();
}
}
```

And it works perfectly fine. But if I try a combination (eg debut and batted) it doesnt work by using this code:

```
else if(!empty($_POST["debut"]) && (!empty($_POST["batted"]))) {
  try
{
$sql = 'INSERT INTO performance SET
    matchid = :matchid,
    playerid = :playerid,
    team = :team,
    debut = 1,
    batted = 1,
    batpos = :batpos,
    runs = :runs,
    ballsfaced = :ballsfaced,
    fours = :fours,
    sixes = :sixes,
    no = 0,
    howout = :howout,
    fielder = :fielder,
    bowler = :bowler,
    bowled = 0,
    ballsbowled = :ballsbowled,
    maidens = :maidens,
    wickets = :wickets,
    runsconceded = :runsconceded,
    catches = :catches,
    stumpings = :stumpings,
    runouts = :runouts';
$s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$s->bindValue(':matchid', $_POST['matchid']);
$s->bindValue(':playerid', $_POST['playerid']);
$s->bindValue(':team', $_POST['team']);
$s->bindValue(':batpos', $_POST['batpos']);
$s->bindValue(':runs', $_POST['runs']);
$s->bindValue(':ballsfaced', $_POST['ballsfaced']);
$s->bindValue(':fours', $_POST['fours']);
$s->bindValue(':sixes', $_POST['sixes']);
$s->bindValue(':howout', $_POST['howout']);
$s->bindValue(':fielder', $_POST['fielder']);
$s->bindValue(':bowler', $_POST['bowler']);
$s->bindValue(':ballsbowled', $_POST['ballsbowled']);
$s->bindValue(':maidens', $_POST['maidens']);
$s->bindValue(':wickets', $_POST['wickets']);
$s->bindValue(':runsconceded', $_POST['runsconceded']);
$s->bindValue(':catches', $_POST['catches']);
$s->bindValue(':stumpings', $_POST['stumpings']);
$s->bindValue(':runouts', $_POST['runouts']);
$s->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
$error = 'Error adding submitted performance.';
include 'error.html.php';
exit();
}
}
```

And in this instance only debut will be inserted as 1. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice this is inside an elseif statement... maybe the first condition is met and this part of the code is never executed?

If this code follows the above if statement, that would definitely be the case.

[edit]

You should check for code duplication as well, if the only difference is setting 'batted' and 'debut' to 0 or 1, there is a much shorter way of doing it without the 'if' statement.

```
$debut = (isset($_POST['debut']) ? 1 : 0);
$batted = (isset($_POST['batted']) ? 1 : 0);
```

Then just bind the values as you did with the others. see http://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples for examples of ternary statements

Comment: Ok, that would make sense. If I swap the order (so the combinations come before the individuals) would that work?

Comment: if this is the only combination you are checking for, yes

Comment: Reserved the order and it worked perfectly, thank you very much